# Django model dynamically query ManyToManyField for values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

The following code works fine for an object that has a ManyToManyField called references like this:

```
res = []
for ref in MyBook.objects.get(id=some_id).references.values("f_name", "l_name"):
    res.append(ref)
```

My question is, how can I dynamically get a pointer to references, given just the string "references"?

Once I have an instance of the MyBook class like this:

```
my_book_model = MyBook.objects.get(id=some_id)
```

I don't know how to get the pointer to my_book_model.references.  Once I have that pointer, then I can just pass the values array to the pointer.values(values_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`getattr(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(my_book_model, 'references').values('f_name', 'l_name')
```

so `getattr(x, 'y')` is thus equivalent to `x.y`. You should however be careful: if an arbitrary string can be used, people might exploit this as a security vulnerability.

Furthermore the use of [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) is often not a good idea either. One can use serializers to convert model objects to dictionaries. [This article <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html) explains problems with using `.values(…)`.